# Generate HTML report using cypress and google lighthouse

Tags: cypress, lighthouse

I want to generate HTML report using cypress and lighthouse.
I have followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://mfrachet.github.io/cypress-audit/guides/lighthouse/installation.html)
I am able to view Google Lighthouse report on console view without passing "html" in config.
When I am trying with param "html" in lighthouse, I am getting error - "CypressError
cy.task('lighthouse') failed with the following error:

> No browser artifacts are either provided or requested"

My spec file is as below :
///

```
    `describe('Generate HTML report', () => {
    it('first test case', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
    // cy.lighthouse();

    const thresholds = {
      "accessibility": 50,
      "best-practices": 50,
      "seo": 50,
      "pwa": 20,
    };
    const LHOptions = { 
      formFactor: 'desktop',
      screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
       };
    const LHConfig = {
      output: "html", //If output is not specified, then the json report will be generated
    };

    cy.lighthouse(thresholds, LHOptions, LHConfig);    
    })
    })`
```

Answer (score 5):

This page [docs/guides/lighthouse/reports](https://github.com/mfrachet/cypress-audit/blob/master/packages/documentation/docs/guides/lighthouse/reports.md) has some useful examples.

From the **Generating HTML reports** section I used the following settings:

```js
const thresholds = {
  "accessibility": 50,
  "best-practices": 50,
  "seo": 50,
  "pwa": 20,
}

const lighthouseOptions = {
  formFactor: 'desktop',
  screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
}

const lighthouseConfig = {
  settings: { output: "html" },
  extends: "lighthouse:default",
}

cy.lighthouse(thresholds, lighthouseOptions, lighthouseConfig)
```

From the **Accessing the raw reports** section I added a simple save-to-disk routine in the task - not using the default task, but adding their example task to get access to the HTML results.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const  fs = require('fs')
const { lighthouse, prepareAudit } = require('@cypress-audit/lighthouse')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        prepareAudit(launchOptions)
      })

      on('task', {
        lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
          const reportHtml = lighthouseReport.report;
          fs.writeFileSync('lhreport.html', reportHtml);
        }),
      })
    },
  },
})
```

This is the saved HTML report:

[image]

Comment: Thanks SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR! It worked for me.

Comment: My script is not working in incognito mode. Mine is cross browser case and I am getting "<third_party_link> didn't send any data"   and in the url address bar, it shows "chrome-error://chromewebdata/" link Any help is appreciated!